# Retrieving attribute of directive created dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code that creates dynamically a directive setting the value of an element `attr1`:

```
   var parentdiv = angular.element ('#parentdiv');
   var elem = angular.element ('<div element></div>');
   elem.attr ('attr1', 1111);
   var content = $compile(elem)($scope);
   parentdiv.append(content);
```

Within directive `element` I change the value of `attr1`. How to retrieve it back in my controller? Note that `attr1` is a scope variable of the directive `element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the attribute value to a variable in scope and then have access to it directly. For example:

```
   var parentdiv = angular.element ('#parentdiv');
   $scope.attr1 = 1111; // define a scope variable
   var elem = angular.element ('<div element attr1="{{attr1}}"></div>');
   var content = $compile(elem)($scope);
   parentdiv.append(content);
```

Now, `$scope.attr1` can be used. Any change will also reflect in the html.